# Event of different types in distributed system - to split or to combine

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, distributed-system

When you have events about different entities, should they go on the same topic or different topics?
Here, I would prefer using a Kafka as a messaging system between Publishers and Consumers. These different sources have different models with few attributes in common and others specific to each model. The raw data/event for these models will be processed separately.

> Q1. Let us consider two different models are acting as publisher or
>   source of the stream. In a distributed system, should they be pushing
>   events to a single topic or respective topics?
>
> Q2. What if an event involves several entities? For example, not just two models as mentioned above but thousands where Kafka
>   latency will suffer, e.g. a purchase-related model, a product, and a
>   customer and a transfer from one account to another involve at least
>   those two accounts.
>
> Q3. For both the cases what schema is preferred AVRO(evolving but for a single model per topic) or JSON schema?

Comment: what kind of data you want in your kafka topics in your example? Do you want the product, buyer, seller and transaction?or something more?

Comment: @abi_pat  If talking about two models it could be any of these. Each model with respective attributes. For thousand of entities represent multiple such models and each model with respective attribute. The list mentioned is not exhaustive and limited to (consider multiple such model) and they are following the similar flow to process the raw event placed in Kafka by respective source.

Comment: If you want to have a generic design to accommodate any number of models in future, you should have one topic. You can use the type of model as key to at least have all the data of one model in same partition. This will also act as identifier at your consumer to identify the type of model and then deciding on how to process it. Needless to say, follow the recommendations and have maximum number of partitions allowed with your infra.

Comment: Very well, that is one of the options, I am trying to collect more data to design a solution for the use case.

Comment: coming to Q3, if you are using single topic for all the models, using AVRO can really be an anti-pattern.

Comment: @abi_pat that's very nice point you brought up. In addition to that, it won't scale very well when looking up headers or certain attributes defining event type in stream. I can visualize the above statement. At this moment it is a gut based decision, I am hoping to have it data based.